# c++ read each 3 elements in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a project and i want to print in order each 3 elements of a string array.So if the string is "cadgfacbda" i want to be printed in the console :

> **"cad gfa cbd a"**

This is the code :

```
        string str("cadgfacbda");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i ; j <  str.size() ; j +=3 )
            {
               cout << str[j]<<" ";
            }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

But what i get is :

> c g c a
>
> a f b
>
> d a d

Comment: You are almost there, have a look at where you increment i and j.

Comment: how should i put it .. ?

Comment: What's wrong with a single `for` loop???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code in one loop only:

```
string str("cadgfacbda");
for(int i = 0 ; i < str.size() ; i++) {
   if(i && i%3==0)
      cout<<" ";
   cout << str[i];
}
cout<<endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it should go something like this:

```
        string str("cadgfacbda");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < str.size() ; i++)
        {
            cout << str[j]<<" ";
            if( i % 3 == 0 )
                cout<<endl;
        }
```

This ofcourse assumes you need new line after every three elements. If you just need spaces then you can try this instead:

```
        string str("cadgfacbda");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < str.size() ; i++)
        {
            cout << str[j];
            if( i % 3 == 0 )
                cout<<" ";
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::string::size_type size_type;

    std::string str("cadgfacbda");

    const size_type STEP_SIZE = 3;

    for(size_type i = 0 ; i < str.size() ; i+=STEP_SIZE)
    {
        std::cout << str.substr(i, STEP_SIZE) << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this is not a copy of my answer?

Comment: Because your answer is not so unique in world :). I was also solving it, and I pasted it before your answer arrive.

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
    string str("cadgfacbda");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.size() ; i++)
    {   
        if(i % 3 == 0 && i != 0) cout << " ";
        cout << str[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<string>
int main()
{
string str("cadgfacbda");
char arr[]=str.to_char();
for(int i=1;i<=strlen(arr);i++)
{
    printf("%c",arr[i-1]);
    if(i%3==0)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Considering the question used `std::string` and `std::cout` why would you use `printf()` and a `char arr[]`? As `str.size()` and `std::cout` would accomplish the same thing in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

This should work too:

```
int main() 
{

    std::string str = "cadgfacbda";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            if ((3 * i + j) < str.length())
                std::cout << str[3 * i + j];
        }
        std::cout << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late I suppose but you could just substring.

```
std::string str("cadgfacbda");

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i += 3) {
    std::cout << str.substr(i, 3) << " ";
}
```

This saves you a ton of code and is imo more readable.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29344f55f20d2fa2)